# ¿Como adapto una página web a otros tamaños?

Tags: css, responsive, mediaqueries

Estoy creando una página web pero cuando pensé que estaba lista me di cuenta que cuando cambiaba a un tamaño de pantalla menor se solapaba,como resuelvo esto?

Comment: Sin tu código y el error exacto no podemos hacer mucho, lee [ask]

Comment: Busca "Responsive" o "Adaptative", son cosas distintas.

Comment: Bienvenido @Jose a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y de paso ganes tu primera medalla, también es muy importante que leas [¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) y [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), favoreciendo así tus chances de obtener una buena recepción por parte de la comunidad.

Answer (score 0):

Para que se vea bien una pagina en cual quier tamaño de pantalla, tienes que usar MediaQueries.

```
@media screen and (max-width: <tamaño-de-la-pantall>) {
    .elemento {
        propiedad1: estilo1;
        propiedad2: estilo2;
        propiedad3: estilo3;
    }
}
```

Puedes averiguar mas de esto en:

[W3SCHOOLS](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp), [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/CSS/Media_queries), [CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/) o en [Desarrolloweb.com](https://desarrolloweb.com/articulos/css-media-queries.html)

Basicamente una media querie (en español "consultas de medios") son útiles cuando deseas modificar tu página web o aplicación en función del tipo de dispositivo (como una impresora o una pantalla) o de características y parámetros específicos (como la resolución de la pantalla o el ancho del viewport del navegador).